# JavaScript - reduce array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working with an array of objects like:

```
[
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: 'American BBQ DOG',
    extra_id: 1,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: 'Mustard (60 g)',
  },
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: 'American BBQ DOG',
    extra_id: 3,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: 'Roasted onions (30 g)',
   
  }
  
]
```

I am trying to reduce the array on matching values for the orderItemId key and achieve an desired output like:

```js
const desired = [
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: 'American BBQ DOG',
    extra: [
      {
        extra_id: 1,
        extra_quantity: 3,
        extra_price: 2,
        extra_name: 'Mustard (60 g)',
      },
      {
        extra_id: 3,
        extra_quantity: 3,
        extra_price: 2,
        extra_name: 'Roasted onions (30 g)',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Any ideas? I tried several logic but failed.

Comment: Please don't put arbitrary tags on your questions, the question doesn't have anything to do with Node, Express, or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. It just uses `Array.find()` to find a previous item with the same `orderItemId`, if found, appends the extras to its `extra` array. If the original array is very large, consider using an object or a `Map` as the accumulator passed to the `.reduce` call and using `Object.values()` later.

If you need to handle extra logic such as adding `product_quantity` or deduplicating `extra`, you'll need to handle that as well.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: "American BBQ DOG",
    extra_id: 1,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: "Mustard (60 g)",
  },
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: "American BBQ DOG",
    extra_id: 3,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: "Roasted onions (30 g)",
  },
];

const reduced = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const {
    extra_id,
    extra_quantity,
    extra_price,
    extra_name,
    ...otherFields
  } = val;

  const existing = acc.find((item) => item.orderItemId === val.orderItemId);
  if (!existing) {
    acc.push({
      ...otherFields,
      extra: [
        {
          extra_id,
          extra_quantity,
          extra_price,
          extra_name,
        },
      ],
    });
    return acc;
  }

  existing.extra.push({ extra_id, extra_quantity, extra_price, extra_name });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(reduced);
```

**Edit**: Here's a version that uses an object as a lookup so it doesn't have to go through the entire accumulated array each time. The `acc` (accumulator) object is basically just an object where the property keys are the `orderItemId` and the value is the new merged object with that key.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: "American BBQ DOG",
    extra_id: 1,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: "Mustard (60 g)",
  },
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: "American BBQ DOG",
    extra_id: 3,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: "Roasted onions (30 g)",
  },
];

const reducedObject = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const {
    extra_id,
    extra_quantity,
    extra_price,
    extra_name,
    ...otherFields
  } = val;

  const existing = acc[val.orderItemId];
  if (!existing) {
    acc[val.orderItemId] = {
      ...otherFields,
      extra: [
        {
          extra_id,
          extra_quantity,
          extra_price,
          extra_name,
        },
      ],
    };
    return acc;
  }

  existing.extra.push({ extra_id, extra_quantity, extra_price, extra_name });
  return acc;
}, {});

const reduced = Object.values(reducedObject);
console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: Thanks. Working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you can use it with different data structure also, whitout declare fields names (or key names).

In practice  comparison and  aggregation.

```js
var alist=[
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: 'American BBQ DOG',
    extra_id: 1,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: 'Mustard (60 g)',
  },
  {
    orderItemId: 180,
    product_id: 1,
    product_quantity: 3,
    product_price: 18,
    product_name: 'American BBQ DOG',
    extra_id: 3,
    extra_quantity: 3,
    extra_price: 2,
    extra_name: 'Roasted onions (30 g)',
   
  }  
];

function jS(o){
    return JSON.stringify(o);
}
function equals(a,b){
    var aa = jS(a);
    var bb = jS(b);
    return aa == bb;
}
function hLen(o){
    return Object.keys(o).length;
}
function hKeys(h){
    return Object.keys(h);
}

function reduce(arr){

    var ha=arr[0];
    var hb=arr[1];
    var hc={};
    var xc1={}; //extra 1 when are different
    var xc2={}; //extra 2 when are different

    maxhlen = Math.max(hLen(ha),hLen(hb));
    akeys = hKeys(ha);
    bkeys = hKeys(hb);

    for(i=0;i<maxhlen;i++){
        k=akeys[i];
        if (ha[k]==hb[k]){
            hc[k]=ha[k];
        }else{
            xc1[k]=ha[k];
            xc2[k]=hb[k];
        }
    }
    
    hc["extra"]=[xc1,xc2];

    return hc;
   
}
res=reduce(alist);
console.log(res);
```

[image]